# Get column name with same type join with other table column name whose category is also same

Tags: sql, join, mapping

I want to know the query for get column name with same type join with other table column name whose category is also same. I tried but can't find the answer.

This is my query

```
SELECT a.name, ac.name FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 ac ON a.id = ac.areaId where ac.positionName = 'cm' or a.type = 2;
```

Details :

```
    Table1
------------------------
|id  |  name   |type   |
-------------------------
|1   |  a      | 1     |
|2   |  b      | 1     |
|3   |  c      | 2     |
|4   |  d      | 2     |
------------------------

table2 

----------------------------------
| name  |  positionName | areaId |
----------------------------------
|x      | cm            | 2      |
|y      | pm            | 3      |
|z      | cm            | 4      |
|q      | cm            | 1      |
----------------------------------

Result 

------------------------
| name  |  name        |
------------------------
| c     |              |
| d     |  z           |
------------------------
```

Comment: What is the expected op?

Comment: what is the relation between the tables?

Comment: I have to find no. of area name with type 2 match with name whose postionName in cm.

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```
SELECT a.name, ac.name from (select * FROM table1 where type = 2 ) a 
left JOIN (select * from table2 where positionName = 'cm' ) ac ON a.id = ac.areaId
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `CASE` statement.

```
 SELECT a.name, CASE WHEN ac.PositionName='cm' THEN ac.name ELSE '' END Name
 FROM table1 a 
    JOIN table2 ac ON a.id = ac.areaId 
 WHERE a.[type] = 2;
```